# Vcpkg libs low speed when execution

Tags: c++, visual-studio, tesseract, vcpkg

I used Vcpkg to install tesseract but by using vcpkg i get low speed code execution, i tested vcpkg to install opencv and compare it to the manuel installation and i had a big difference in time 2 seconde without vcpkg and 13 seconde with the vcpkg, any one has an idea?

Comment: Sounds like you are using debug instead of release libs.

Comment: yes i already fix it , you are right, thanx anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change from debug to release mode